# if $g_n=f*f*...*f$ show that f is a trigonometric polynomial

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, fourier-analysis, convolution

Let f be a periodic $ 2\pi $ and continuous function.
given $$g_1=f,g_2=f*f,\dots g_{n}=\underbrace{f*f*f*f}_{n\,times} $$
1.assuming $ f(x)=D_N=\sum_{n=-N}^{N}e^{inx} $ prove that $f=g_n $

2. assuming $ g_{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}f $ uniformally.

for 1:
Using induction for case $n=1 $ $ f=f $ is easy.
We know the Fourier coefficients $$ \hat{f}\left(m\right)=\begin{cases}
1 & \left|m\right|\le N\\
0 & else
\end{cases} $$

Assuming $g_n =f $, applying $*f $ to both sides we get that
$$g_{n+1}=\underbrace{f*f*\dots*f}_{n+1\,times}=f*f $$
Because of convolution theorem : $$ \left(\hat{f}\left(m\right)\right)^{n+1}=\begin{cases}
1\cdot1=1 & \left|m\right|\le N\\
0\cdot0 & else
\end{cases}=\hat{f}\left(m\right) $$
Hence the fourier coefficients for $\left(\hat{f}\left(m\right)\right)^{n}=\hat{f}\left(m\right) $ we can infer that $ \hat{g}_{n}\left(m\right)=\left(\hat{f}\left(m\right)\right)^{n}=\hat{f}\left(m\right) $ hence $ f=g_n $

For part 2:
had a bit of trouble here. my line of thought was that if we contradict Riemann-Lebesgue theorem we can prove it.
Lets assume f is not a trigonometric polynomial.

Because f is continuous Riemann Lebesgue applies to it so we know that $\hat{f}\left(m\right)\xrightarrow{m\to\infty}0 $

Because of convolution theorem we once again get$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\hat{f}\left(m\right)\right)^{n}=\hat{f}\left(m\right) $$ for all m.
assuming for some large m $ \hat{f}\left(m\right)\ne0 $ we can divide both sides by $ \hat{f}(m) 
$ We can get $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\hat{f}\left(m\right)=1 $ therefore $\hat{f}(m)$ is a root of unity, but not 0. which is a contradiction to Riemann-Lebesgue.

Comment: You seem to be using "$f$" in at least two different senses... can you clarify?

Comment: For the first part. $ f(x)$ is a Dirichlet kernel for some $N $.
For the second part, we don't know anything about f other than the fact it is continuous and periodic. 
The Fourier coefficients are given by $ \hat{f}\left(m\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits _{-\pi}^{\pi}f\left(x\right)e^{-imx}dx $

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks!